# Travelling with Swiss Residence Permit -from Turkey to Belgium

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, switzerland, turkish-citizens

Can I travel from Turkey to Belgium with a Swiss residence permit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you also have a passport. The permit alone is not sufficient.

From [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=TR&AR=CH&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=BE&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the database used by Airlines:

> - Passport required.
>
>   - Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to residents of Switzerland must be valid on arrival.
> - Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a residence permit
>     issued by Switzerland for a maximum stay of 90 days

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can travel with Swiss residence permitt into Schengen country for upto 90 days with any 180 day period without a visa. Answer is from official 
[State Secretariat For Migration](https://www.sem.admin.ch/sem/en/home/themen/einreise/faq.html#5).

> [image]